# Advice on new HDD and RAM for 2008 iMac

Tags: mac, upgrade

I am looking to play some games on my iMac using VMware or BootCamp and some native games like Call of Duty.

I am looking at buying this HDD: http://www.ebuyer.com/product/173804 and adding 4 GB or 6 GB of RAM (not 100% certain which yet, probably 4 GB).

Will adding this to my iMac which currently has the stock 320 GB HDD and 2 GB RAM increase my performance and future gameplaying or should I think about upgrading the whole machine?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/47851/are-there-big-differences-in-speed-between-different-hard-drives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely go for as much memory as possible, especially if you are planning on using virtual machines.

For games, the performance of the hard drive probably only affects loading times. As for the Samsung hard drive, I have that particular drive for media storage, but I install my games on an earlier Samsung (320GB) model - so I can't really comment on the performance. Another option is whether an SSD is suitable, but note that your iMac's graphics capabilities and CPU will be the most important factors for gaming performance.